# Semantic versioning issue and npm 5 or above

Tags: angular, npm, version, semantic-versioning

Can you tell me why do we need `NPM 5` or above to avoid semantic versioning problems? In other words, how can we avoid it using `package-lock.json` file? Can't we avoid this issue if we use the same `package.json` file on all the development machine for the same project? I'm a little bit confused here.Hope you'll give a feedback for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be avoided if your `package.json` file lists packages like:

```
"@angular/core": "4.2.6",
"@angular/forms": "4.2.6",
"@angular/http": "4.2.6",
```

instead of

```
"@angular/core": "^4.2.6",
"@angular/forms": "^4.2.6",
"@angular/http": "~4.2.6",
```

By removing the tilde or cap(~, ^) sign from `package.json` npm will install exact same version on all machines. But its safe to add tilde or cap sign, so you can install small version updates of your packages without updating the file. But sometime this can cause issues, when package developer packs a breaking change in small version.

`package-lock.json` will do the same, it removes the tilde or cap sign, and marks the concrete version of package to be installed. And will make lock file priority to get the package version information while installing the packages.

Edit: Nice explanation from [Angular University](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7HFNBwbOCM) on Youtube.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice explanation :)

Comment: Currently, my auto-generated package-lock has tilde and carat sign prefixed with version numbers. But I want to lock the versions of the dependency. Should I remove those carets and tildes manually and check the package-lock to source countrol? Is that a good practise?

Comment: @Murtuza yes, you can do this, but don't update `package-lock.json` file. Update the `package.json` file, and auto generate `package-lock.json` file.